# Store result of ExcecuteNonQuery() result into GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am looking suggestions for store my ExecuteNonQuery() into  .csv file.

I am trying to execute .sql file in ASP.NET and try to store it's result into csv file.

Can anyone know how to do this?

My code snippet:

```
   protected void Btn_result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {   
       string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;

       string auctionFacilityProfitAdjustment = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Profit Adjustment Data\Auction Facility Profit Adjustment.sql");

       SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       connection.Open();

       Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
       int count = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(auctionFacilityProfitAdjustment);

   }
```

And result stores into GridView. And then csv file.

For eg. My result is 2 affected rows.

So, I want to store it into GridView like:

101 ABC 123467890

102 HHG 9876543210

103 JJL 3794826892

Like wise.

Comment: The result is an `int`, it represents the rows affected by this sql-query(that dodesn't return anything apart from that). How do you want to show that single int in the GridView?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery only returns an affected record count, notice the NonQuery part.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns single integer value only.

Comment: Then any other solution for query? I mean any other method which can send me result set so I can bind my result into GridView.

I want show all rows in GridView.

Ex.

 101   ABC    1234567890
 102   DXS     9876543210

And like wise.